# Rails Simple Form input with Font-Awesome

Tags: simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want to use icons instead of text for labels in a horizontal simple_form. However, I am unable to separate the text from the icons

```
= simple_form_for @user, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }, wrapper: :horizontal_form do |f|

  # shows 'username' label only
  = f.input :username

  # shows icon with 'username'
  = f.input :username, label_html: {class: "fas fa-user"}

  # shows nothing
  = f.input :username, label_html: {class: "fas fa-user"}, label: false
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to do the same, there is a simpler/cleaner way :

```
= f.label :username, label: ('<i class="fas fa-user"></i>').html_safe
= f.text_field :username
```

Also work with I18n localization file :

```
(en.yml)
username: '<i class="fas fa-user"></i>'
```

then

```
= f.label :name, label: t(:username).html_safe
= f.text_field :username
```

Using simple_form (4.1.0)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wrapper_html` option:

```
= f.input :username, label: false, wrapper_html: { class: 'fa fa-user' }
```

You will probably have to add some css to make it look the way you want. For example, to get the icon on a different line than the input, I had to add `display: block` to the icon.

[image: Font Awesome Icon]

Answer (score 0):

`wrapper_html:` and `label_html:` were complicated, so I just did it manually

```
.row
  .col-3
    .text-right
      i.fas.fa-user
  .col-9
    = f.input_field :username, label: false, class: 'form-control'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented this very thing on my own project. There was a really simple solution.

First, I created a helper for outputting fontawesome icons. In `app/helpers/font_awesome_helper.rb`:

```
module FontAwesomeHelper
  def fa_icon(icon, style: :regular)
    content_tag(:i, "", class: [icon_style_class(style), icon_class(icon)].join(" "))
  end

  private
    def icon_class(icon)
      "fa-#{icon}"
    end

    def icon_style_class(style)
      case style
      when :light, :l
        "fal"
      when :regular, :r
        "far"
      when :solid, :s
        "fas"
      when :duotone, :duo, :d
        "fad"
      else
        "fa"
      end
    end
end
```

You can extend this further to support inverting icon colours, flipping horizontally, etc.

Finally, you can use your `fa_icon` helper in your simple-form input:

```
= f.input :username, label: fa_icon("user", style: :solid)
```