# How to use FontAwesome with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, simple-form

this my first post!

I want to use a fontawesome icon :
`<i class="fas fa-star"></i>`

in a simple_form form.
`<%= f.input :rating, collection: 0..5 %>`

What is the best way to do this?
[a ⭐️ with 'rating' a side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TzhS.png)
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add an example how you want it to look so that someone might help you with that and be as much broad as possible with a question.

Comment: Thx Rafayet, I put a pictures with my question 

Comment: Duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945633/rails-simple-form-input-with-font-awesome

Comment: thanks Shoaib
I so it after my post.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way is using `wrapper_html:`

`<%= f.input :rating, wrapper_html: { class: 'fas fa-star' }, collection: 0..5 %>`

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945633/rails-simple-form-input-with-font-awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945633/rails-simple-form-input-with-font-awesomehttps://)

[more info on simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form)